# Javascript - Inserting unique elements in Array: Multidimensional check x Temporary unidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I don't know if it's a stupid question, but here it comes:

Imagine an array of unordered objects like:
 `[{id:4, name:"a"},{id:2, name:"b"},{id:3, name:"ee"},{id:1, name:"fe"},.....]`.

This array is dinamically created inside a loop using javascript, but, everytime  I'll push something to the array I must check if an object with the same `id` exists and only pushs the newones.

Which one is faster:

1) At every loop check manualy the entire array.

or

2) Create a temporary unidimensional array only with `ids` and use `indexOf` to check if the new object `id` is present and then, if not present at the temporary array, add it to the original array.

Comment: The best way to know is to test it, normally I would suggest using http://jsperf.com/ but it's currently down.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni I'm wondering, is it down for a while, will it come back? Or it just only online for a fixed time every day?

Comment: Also, you can try to use a `Object` to store those `id`, as hash lookup should be O(1)...

Comment: How big is the array going to be? Besides, I think that objects are faster for such checks. I bet that `typeof (object[id]) !== "undefined"` is way faster than an entire loop

Comment: @fuyushimoya they're addressing some performance issues it seems https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/18#issuecomment-113569132

Comment: The array can be up to 2000 records.... I'll try to change the structure repeating the id both as index and as a object field, but I don't know if it will still work with other externals js... Let's see. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var a = []
var o = { id:10, name:"xyz" }
if(typeof a[o.id]=="undefined") {
    a[o.id] = { name:o.name }
}
```

? That should be fastest for most machines. Or to not change your object structure

```
a[o.id] = { id:o.id, name:o.name }
```

But the better approach would be

```
function getA(i) { if (typeof a[i] == "undefined") return null;
    return { id:i, name:a[i].name }; }
```

Comment: The key sentence should be "JavaScript guarantees order of O(1) for lookup using [ ] operator".

Comment: I don't use javascript that extensive that I can surely quote such guarantees. But that's what I assumed. Thank you for the quote!

Comment: note that if you want to serialize `a` (`JSON.stringify(a)`) and you have a sparse array, you will get 'null' elements.